# How to avoid or skip some private method for XUnit test?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit

Let's say I have written a unit test to test a public method in XUnit.

```
[Fact]
public void MethodA_WhenSomething_ThenReturnNull()
{
    // Code removed for brevity.

    // Assert
}
```

This is MethodA.

```
public void MethodA() {
  MethodOne();
  MethodTwo();
  MethodThree();
}
```

MethodOne, MethodTwo and MethodTree are all private method. Is there a way to skip a private method (ie MethodTwo) while running my unit test for MethodA? The reason I want to skip methodTwo is because methodTwo calling a stored procedure and it causes error in Xunit. But I know the stored procedure is running fine without issue, so it is okay for me to skip this method.

And the moment, I am using this way.

```
public void MethodA() {
  MethodOne();

  #if DEBUG == false
    MethodTwo();
  #endif

  MethodThree();
}
```

If there is a better way, I wish not to put `If DEBUG`

Comment: There are two types of mocking frameworks: constrained and unconstrained. The former: Moq, NSubstitute, FakeItEasy - allow you to fake only virtual members. The latter: TypeMock, JustMock, MS Fakes, Prig, Ionad.Fody, Pose, Harmony, MethodRedirect - allow you to fake anything you want: non-virtual, private and static members, sealed classes and so on. This way, you can substitute MethodTwo.

Comment: The more ideologically pure solution is to mock whatever dependency your code has that causes it to call a stored procedure.

Comment: To add to @DanielMann's comment and perhaps make it obvious, refactor the SP call to another dependency, then mock that dependency.

Comment: @DanielMann, got any tutorial or example link to share on this?

Comment: I define those methods with the internal access modifier then I use  InternalsVisibleTo attribute to expose them to my unit test project. Ref. https://improveandrepeat.com/2019/12/how-to-test-your-internal-classes-in-c/

Comment: Your question is about how to mock/substitute the private method. You've accepted an answer that doesn't do that. If you can change the access modifier of your method, then you should have directly written about it in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of problem is typically solved via `Moq.Protected`.

So, you need to change `private` accessor to `protected` at least for `MethodTwo`.
But I would suggest to change all accessors to `protected`.

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public void MethodA()
    {
        MethodOne();
        MethodTwo();
        MethodThree();
    }
    protected void MethodOne() { ... }
    protected void MethodTwo() { ... }
    protected void MethodThree() { ... }
}
```

With this, the mock setup would look like this:

```
using Moq.Protected;

...
var mockSomeClass = new Mock<SomeClass>();

mockSomeClass.Protected()
             .Setup("MethodTwo")
             .Verifiable();
```

Additionally you can setup a `Callback` to write something out the test output

```
const string toBeMockedMethodName = "MethodTwo";
mockSomeClass.Protected()
             .Setup(toBeMockedMethodName)
             .Callback(() => TestContext.Progress.Writeline($"{toBeMockedMethodName} has been called."))
             .Verifiable();
```

References:

- [Mocking protected members](https://riptutorial.com/moq/example/27613/mocking-protected-members)
- [Protected Members - Unit testing in C#](https://docs.educationsmediagroup.com/unit-testing-csharp/moq/protected-members)
- [Moq - how to mock a protected method of an internal class with no parameter-less constructor](http://lukasz-lysik.github.io/unit%20tests/2013/04/18/moq-mock-only-one-protected-method-of-an-internal-class-with-no-parameter-less-constructor.html)

Answer (score 2):

If your private method depends on some external service, then you can create make a mock of it and mark it verifiable.

```
[Fact]
public void MethodA_WhenSomething_ThenReturnNull()
{
    var barService = new Mock<Bar>();
    barService.Setup(x => x.DoSomething()).Verifiable();
    ///
}

public class Foo
{
    public void MethodA()
    {
        MethodOne();
        MethodTwo();
        MethodThree();
    }

    private void MethodThree() => System.Console.WriteLine();

    private void MethodTwo() => new Bar().DoSomething();

    private void MethodOne() => System.Console.WriteLine();
    
}

public class Bar
{
    public void DoSomething() => System.Console.WriteLine("....");
}
```

Comment: I tried but can't get it to work. The thing is MethodTwo() uses some private class field also.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways that you can use to replace the private method. Let's use the [MethodRedirect](https://github.com/spinico/MethodRedirect) library.

Let's say there is the following class:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public void MethodA()
    {
        MethodOne();
        MethodTwo();
        MethodThree();
    }
    private void MethodOne() { }
    private void MethodTwo() =>
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    private void MethodThree() { }
}
```

```
var sc = new SomeClass();
sc.MethodA(); // An exception will be thrown here.
```

The above library does not have a nuget package. Therefore, we simply copy three files from [sources](https://github.com/spinico/MethodRedirect/tree/master/Sources): Extensions.cs, MethodOperation.cs, MethodToken.cs.

Then write the following unit test:

```
[Fact]
public void MethodA_WhenCalled_NotThrow()
{
    var sut = new SomeClass();
    var fake = new Fake();

    MethodInfo privateMethod = sut.GetType().GetMethod("MethodTwo", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    MethodInfo redirectMethod = fake.GetType().GetMethod("Redirect", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    var token = privateMethod.RedirectTo(redirectMethod);

    sut.MethodA(); // should not throw

    token.Restore();
}
```

Auxiliary class whose method will be used as a replacement

```
public class Fake
{
    static void Redirect() { }
}
```

Comment: I tried but it is not working. When it reaches MethodTwo, the exception is `System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'`

Comment: After that I enable `Enable native code debugging` but it is still running that MethodTwo without skipping it.

Comment: @Steve - It works for me. Give more information: the exact signatures of your methods, the version of the framework used (.NET or .NET Core) and other necessary information.

Comment: My service project is in netstandard2.1 and my test project is in netcoreapp3.1